# How to calculate the max click interval using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, bigdata

I have dataset like this which indicates when an IP click the link:

`ip      time`

I want to calculate the maximum click interval of every different IP.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you're looking for something like the following.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ip':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'time':pd.date_range('01-15-16 12:00:00',
                   periods=9)})
df_grp = df.groupby('ip')['time'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

This calculates the time difference between the first and the last clicks associated with an IP.